# Hover over: Button Change using Flatyle properties C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, hover

Im working in WinForms I have 4 buttons on my form. I want to be able to hover my mouse over it and change the FlatStyle from Flat to System.

My code transforms all the buttons to System Style when you hover your mouse over it, that's not exactly what i had in mind.

All the buttons should remain flat until you hover over them. If you hover off the button it should turn back into flat button

```
    private void All_Button_Hover_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn_Back.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
        Btn_Forward.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
        btn_Print.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
        btn_Open.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion of how you could handle this.

You're already setting all the buttons in a single event method, which is fine. Since the button that triggered the event is stored in `sender`, you could just use that:

```
private void All_Button_Hover_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
}
```

To change the buttons back to the original `FlatStyle.Flat` style, you'll probably want to subscribe all of their `MouseLeave` events to a method as well:

```
private void All_Button_Hover_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
}
```

Comment: I actually don't have another method that flips them back to the original style i'm still new to programming.

Comment: I was thinking about putting a if-else statement something like 'if(Back_button.Hover) do something ''' Else ((Button)sender).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;